# Gammu: make voice call, with custom mp3

Tags: gammu

Can I make a voice call with custom mp3 (when the person answers the phone call), with Gammu in Linux?

Otherwise, are there alternatives to Gammu (in Linux), so that you can send SMS and make calls with the help of an mp3 file?

Comment: It should be possible unless you have a problem. There is also a GUI called Wammu.